# List<string>. Как сохранить/прочитать в XML?

Tags: c#

Создаю дерево

```
// Заполнение дерева узлами
        public void createRootNode()
        {
            // Create the root node.
            // Создаем корневой узел.
            TreeNode Node_1 = new TreeNode("Node_1");

            // Add some additional nodes.
            // Добавьте некоторые дополнительные узлы.
            Node_1.Nodes.Add("Node_1_1");
            Node_1.Nodes.Add("Node_1_2");

            // Add the root nodes to the TreeView.
            // Добавьте корневые узлы в TreeView.
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(Node_1);

            // Create the root node.
            // Создаем корневой узел.
            TreeNode Node_2 = new TreeNode("Node_2");

            // Add some additional nodes.
            // Добавьте некоторые дополнительные узлы.
            Node_2.Nodes.Add("Node_2_1");
            Node_2.Nodes.Add("Node_2_1");

            // Add the root nodes to the TreeView.
            // Добавьте корневые узлы в TreeView.
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(Node_2);
        }
```

Пробую сохранить/прочитать в XML следующим способом.
**Класс CreateList.cs**

```
public class CreateList
    {
        public List<string> createListBuild()
        {
            var itemsList = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

            return itemsList;
        }
    }
```

**Класс ConfigWrapper.cs**

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", ElementName = "collection")]

    public class ConfigWrapper
    {
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public List<string> Items { get; set; }

    }
```

**Класс WriteReadList.cs**

```
public class WriteReadList
    {
        // Запись в XML
        public void WriteXML(List<string> itemsList)
        {   
            var cfgIn = new ConfigWrapper { Items = itemsList };
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigWrapper));
            //string fileContent = "ListXML";
            // string fileContent = @".\ListXML.xml";
            string fileContent = @".\ListXML.xml";

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                xs.Serialize(sw, cfgIn);
                fileContent = sw.ToString();
                // Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
            }
        }

        public void ReadXML(string fileContent)
        {
            ConfigWrapper cfgOut = null;
            using (var sr = new StringReader(fileContent))
            {
                var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigWrapper));
                cfgOut = xs.Deserialize(sr) as ConfigWrapper;
                // cfgOut.Dump(); //view in LinqPad
                // if (cfgOut != null)
                    // yields 'item2'
                    // Console.WriteLine(cfgOut.Items[1]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Логику реализую следующими кнопками:

```
List<string> listWork;
  CreateList createList;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listWork = createList.createListBuild();
        }

// Сохранить в XML
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Конфигурация обёртки
            ConfigWrapper config = new ConfigWrapper();
            config.Items = listWork;

            WriteReadList writeReadList = new WriteReadList();

            writeReadList.WriteXML(config.Items);

        }
```

У меня не получается сделать чтобы код работал

Как сделать правильно?
Как сделать чтобы List сохранялся/читался из XML файла, который расположен рядом с "*.exe" файлом проекта?
Или как это сделать более проще?

Comment: 1. А что не работает? 2. Приложите XML, который пытаетесь парсить.
3. Приложите код ошибки

Comment: @Arantler Ошибок нет. Не создаётся файл XML